# SQL Query to select row having two or more identical columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, duplicates

I have table SUPPLIER

```
    line    name     country    supplier     city
    1        A         UK         Google     London
    1        A         UK         Apple      London
    1        A         UK         Amazon     London
    2        B         UK         Microsoft  London
    3        C         UK         Amazon     London
    4        D         UK         Google     Oxford
    4        D         UK         Apple      Oxford
    4        D         UK         Amazon     Oxford
```

I am looking to create a case statement that in case the same line number appears more than once,  it will select a particular supplier, in this case "Google" when the city is London, else if city is Oxford and same line appears more than once, it will select supplier "Amazon"

Expected Result

```
    line    name     country    supplier     city
    1        A         UK         Google     London
    2        B         UK         Microsoft  London
    3        C         UK         Amazon     London
    4        D         UK         Amazon     Oxford
```

Comment: What is your primary key

Comment: line is my primary Key

Comment: Some straightforward solutions require a primary key to be used for a join. `line` can't be your primary key, because it's not unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where (supplier, city) = (select t2.supplier, t2.city
                          from t t2
                          where t2.line = t.line  -- and perhaps other conditions as well
                          order by (case when (supplier, city) in ('Google', 'London') then 1
                                         when (supplier, city) in ('Amazon', 'Oxford') then 1
                                         else 3
                                    end)
                          limit 1
                         );
```

You can readily add more prioritization conditions to the `order by` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query

```
select *
  from
(
 select line, name, country, max(supplier), city
   from tab
  group by line, name, country, city
 having count(supplier)=1
union all
select line, name, country, 
       case when city = 'London' then max(supplier) 
            when city = 'Oxford' then min(supplier)
        end supplier, city
  from tab
 group by line, name, country, city
 having count(supplier)>1 
 ) q
 order by q.line;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ea39f9019cafd4e7a1ff5b1e0cc5e62a)</kbd>

Comment: What would happen in the case the table was much longer with more cities and 5 suppliers in a line? Would  max and min still be the case?

Comment: @cshion What if you prepared such samples to get such results ?

Answer (score 0):

Join the table to a query consisting of the rows you put your conditions on and then group by line, name, country, city:

```
select 
  t.line,
  t.name,
  t.country,
  coalesce(max(u.supplier), max(t.supplier)) supplier,
  t.city
from tablename t left join (
  select 'Google' supplier, 'London' city 
  union all 
  select 'Amazon', 'Oxford'
) u on u.supplier = t.supplier and u.city = t.city 
group by t.line, t.name, t.country, t.city
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=26f7c37c87333fdc43b79dca858ab4e2).
Results:

```
> line | name | country | supplier  | city  
> ---: | :--- | :------ | :-------- | :-----
>    1 | A    | UK      | Google    | London
>    2 | B    | UK      | Microsoft | London
>    3 | C    | UK      | Amazon    | London
>    4 | D    | UK      | Amazon    | Oxford
```